# NASM automatically escaping shellcode initialized in .data

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, nasm, shellcode

I am attempting to write a piece of assembly code which will perform operations on some shell code I have initialized in .data

My initialization is as as follows:

```
section .data
        shellcode: db "\x31\xc9\xf7\xe1\x51\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80", 0
```

When I attempt to load the array holding the shell code into a register, it is automatically escaped, breaking my program:

[image]

[image]

I assembled and linked as follows:

```
nasm -f elf32 -g encryptor_assembly.asm -o encryptor_assembly.o
gcc -m32 -g encryptor_assembly.o -o encryptor_assembly
```

Is there a way to avoid this from happening? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You presumably need `-zexecstack` for gcc to link the `.data` section into executable memory.  Also, obviously you're just getting a *pointer* to the memory into EAX, and that doesn't change the memory contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nasm only interpretes C-style escape sequences inside character strings delimited with backticks.  To fix your code, replace the double quotes with backticks like this:

```
shellcode: db `\x31\xc9\xf7\xe1\x51\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80`, 0
```

Refer to [the manual](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.14.02/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.4.4) for details.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!